# How to break out of begin block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, program-flow

How can I break out of the begin block and jump to the rescue block?

```
def function
  begin
    @document = Document.find_by(:token => params[:id])
    next if @document.sent_at < 3.days.ago # how can I skip to the rescue block here?
    @document.mark_as_viewed
  rescue
    flash[:error] = "Document has expired."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

My attempt using `next` doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you're using `rescue` correctly...

Comment: One quick thing if you do this a lot... try using `def...rescue...end` as opposed to `def...begin...rescue...end...end`

Comment: @kddeisz 's comment is really helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you could raise an error. That's how begin/rescue blocks work. It's not a good idea, though - using error handling for business logic is generally frowned upon.

It seems as though it would make much more sense to refactor as a simple conditional. Something like:

```
def function
  @document = Invoice.find_by(:token => params[:id])
  if @document.sent_at < 3.days.ago
    flash[:error] = "Document has expired."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    @document.mark_as_viewed 
  end
end
```

It seems as though you've confused a few different kinds of block-related keywords here:

Error handling (`begin`/`rescue`/`end`) is for cases where you think something you try might raise an error, and respond in a particular way to it.

`next` is for iteration - when you're looping through a collection and want to skip to the next element.

Conditionals (`if`, `unless`, `else`, etc.) are the usual way for checking the state of something and executing different bits of code depending on it.

Comment: I was going to make an answer that did exactly this.  I'll just upvote you.  This is the correct way to do it, don't use `rescue` for simple business logic if nothing exceptional is happening.

Comment: Thanks but it's possible to get a nil error for `@document` that way, isn't it? That was the reason I used the begin/rescue block.

Comment: @Tintin81 The API says that `.find_by` is equivalent to `.where`, so if there's no matching record, it should simply set `@document` to `nil`, which you could then check for in order to respond correctly (probably with a status 404? depends on your logic)